# PHP echo returns a Json composed string prefixed by :<!-- -->

Tags: php, angularjs

Could someone help me please? 
I am doing a $http request from angular, requesting a php script to retrieve data from mysql. Within the php string I compose a Json such as:

```
$outp="";
$result=$con->query($sql);
while ($obj=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
$outp .= '{"name":"'  . $obj["LegalEntityLongName"] . '",';

$outp .= '"distance":"'. $obj["Distance"] . '",';

$outp .= '"latitude":"'. $obj["Latitude"] . '",';

$outp .= '"longitude":"'. $obj["Longitude"] . '"}';
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';

$result->free();


$con->close();
echo $outp;
```

My angular controller ...is

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {
$scope.data=response.data;
```

produces this

```
    <!-- --> {"records":[
    {"name":"Shadana    Kitchen","distance":"0.5448844737134834","latitude":"-33.8053","longitude":"151.18"},
    {"name":"The Good Green Grocer","distance":"1.1798241450689664","latitude":"-33.8075","longitude":"151.173"},
    {"name":"Eco Herbs","distance":"2.334899775995475","latitude":"-33.81","longitude":"151.161"},
    {"name":"Marc Smith ","distance":"3.2245850404758944","latitude":"-33.8051","longitude":"151.15"}
    ]}
```

... it gives me a string prefixed by an empty comment html tag

Do I need to manually remove that prefix and convert the rest of the string into an object, as angular cannot read the object as an array in this format?

What am i doing wrong, I am totally lost...I am new here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't create your own json. You just make your life too complicated. use `json_encode` function.

Comment: I second the comments on making your own JSON, using `json_encode` is best.   The <!-- --> isn't coming from this code snippet.  It is either a) before this code extract or b) after this extract and you're using output buffering around this code (e.g. a function call).

Comment: that html comment isn't creating itself. Must be in file or includes you are calling with ajax

Comment: Hi, thanks you all for your responses, much appreciated. @Jack, thanks for the heads up, I was leaning towards an embedded string /escape sequence somewhere but it was not obvious, until your comment and charlietfl prompted me to look further.  On my config file (which included) I had commented a whole block (between <?php //something ?>) prior to another block uncommented, with the credentials for mysql on my local host also within the php tags. Once i removed this bit of commented block, it all worked! Thanks to all!!